# How to to keep the text from a JS function when an form empties?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mb-3">
        <h3>Welcome, Please register with Us</h3>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <img src="images/login.png" alt="Login" width="100" height="80">
            <br>
            <b>Full name</b>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="fullname" class="form-control" name="txtFullName" placeholder="John Watson" required>
            <br>
            <b>User Name</b>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="txtUserName" placeholder="john@example.com" required>
            <br>
            <b>Password</b>
            <br>
            <input type="password" id="first_pass" class="form-control" name="txtpassword" placeholder="minimum 6 characters" required>
            <br>
            <b>Repeat Password</b>
            <br>
            <input type="password" id="second_pass" class="form-control" name="txtpassword" placeholder="minimum 6 characters" required>

            <script src="scripts/register.js"></script>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="rememberMe">Remember Me
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" onclick="verifyid()">
        </form>
        
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS script is:

```
function verifyid (){
    str1 = document.getElementById("first_pass").value;
    str2 = document.getElementById("second_pass").value;
    if (str1 == str2) {
            displayOutput = "You are our new user";
        } else {
            displayOutput = "The passwords do not match";
        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = displayOutput;
}
```

Also, the CSS script is not really important, so I will not include it.

When I run the HTML file, the JS function works great, also the message is printed correctly. My problem is that when I click "register," the form is emptied (as it should); however, the JS message print is also deleted. It happens so fast that there is no anyone can read JS function message.

Is there a way to allow the form to the emptied (as it should), but keep the message at the bottom?

This pic shows how I would like the message and HTML page displayed if the user did not type the same passwords.

[image: HTML output]

Comment: I am new to HTML and JS. Pardon if this is very basic, but I did not find the solution anywhere.

Comment: Well, you can just pass the event when you click the Register button ie: onclick="verifyid(event)" ———————-then, receive it in your function and prevent default ie: function verifyid(e) { e.preventDefault(); //add rest of your code}

Comment: Just edited it .. let me know if it’s not clear yet

Comment: You’re not passing the click event to verifyid function neither in html nor js.. you don’t have the line of preventing default as well

Comment: @SalwaA.Soliman I tried your solution and it does not do what I need. I need the form to go back to the original placeholders and just display the message at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The submit buttons are submitting your form (so reloading your page). That's why text disappears rapidly after clicking on 'submit button'

Change the buttons to `type="button"`.

Comment: When I change to button, instead of submitting, the boxes from username and passwords are not emptied. They keep previous values. I need them to be emptied. To be precis, not the username, only the passwords.

Comment: You can store text in localstorage

Comment: I only want to keep the username if the passwords do not match. If the passwords match, the user is registered so everything should be deleted, and just display "You are our new user"

Answer (score 0):

Pass the click event to your function so that you can prevent default behavior of submitting a form (reloading page)

1- replace onclick="verifyid()"

With onclick="verifyid(**event**)"

2- receive event in your function and prevent the default behavior

```
function verifyid (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  str1 = document.getElementById("first_pass").value;
  str2 = document.getElementById("second_pass").value;
  if (str1 == str2) {
        displayOutput = "You are our new user";
        const inputs= document.querySelectorAll(“form input:not([type="submit"])”);
        inputs.forEach(input=>input.value=“”)
    } else {
        displayOutput = "The passwords do not match";
        document.getElementById("first_pass").value=“”
        document.getElementById("second_pass").value=“”
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = displayOutput;
```

}

Comment: I tried your solution, and it does not do what I need. I need the form to go back to the original placeholders and just display the message at the bottom. In your solution, the form keeps the user's incorrect entry.